# How to access HTML response variables in Java code

Tags: java, html, servlets

I am trying to create a Java program which does some actions with the responses to an HTML survey. Here is what I have done so far:

HTML form code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Patient Survey</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Patient Survey</h2>
    <p>Please answer in the following questions and press the "Submit" button.</p>



<form name="patientForm" method="post" action="patientServlet" >
Full name: <input type="text" name="Name" value=""><br>

<BR>
Select your state:
<select name="State">
<OPTION VALUE=>
<OPTION VALUE=AL>California
<OPTION VALUE=AK>Washington
<OPTION VALUE=AZ>Maine
<OPTION VALUE=PA>Pennsylvania
<OPTION VALUE=MN>Minnesota
</select>
<BR>
<BR>
Age (optional)
<SELECT NAME="MyAge" ><OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE=1 > -20
<OPTION VALUE=2 > 20 - 25
<OPTION VALUE=3 > 26 - 30
<OPTION VALUE=4 > 31 - 35
<OPTION VALUE=5 > 36 - 40
<OPTION VALUE=6 > 41 - 45
<OPTION VALUE=7 > 46 - 50
<OPTION VALUE=8 > 51 - 55
<OPTION VALUE=9 > 56 - 60
<OPTION VALUE=10 > 61+
</SELECT>

<BR>
<BR>

List any previous injuries: <input type="text" injury="Previous     Injuries" value=""><br>

<p>
<input type="checkbox" name="Injury" value=>Diabetes<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Injury" value=>Cholesterol<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Injury" value=>Back Fracture<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Injury" value=>Leg Fracture<br><br>
</p>


<input type="submit" value="Submit" />


</form>





</body>
</html>
```

Java Class code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/patientServlet")
public class patientServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,     IOException {

        // read form fields
        String name = request.getParameter("Name");
        String state = request.getParameter("State");
        String age = request.getParameter("MyAge");
        String injury = request.getParameter("Injury");

        System.out.println("name: " + name);
        System.out.println("injury: " + injury);




    }

}
```

However, when I run the HTML file in Chrome, nothing happens.

In addition, when I add the following code to my Java class, the error "Page load failed with error: The requested URL was not found on this server." pops up:

```
    //get response writer
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

            // build HTML code
            String htmlResponse = "<html>";
            htmlResponse += "<h2>Your name is: " + name + "<br/>";      
            htmlResponse += "Your injury is: " + injury + "</h2>";    
            htmlResponse += "</html>";

            // return response
            writer.println(htmlResponse);
```

What should I do? Should I start over with a different method?

**Please let me know how I can access my HTML response variables in my code.**

**Another question is: when I use this class in my main method, what HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse objects do I put in? Where do I get those?**

Thanks!

Comment: Well everything seems fine. May be try to make the name of the class name start with capital letter and add @override annotation. All i am saying is a try in wild. :D. Also you should ensure that your files are placed inside the server directory. You may have forgot that.

Comment: `The requested URL was not found` is a deployment issue, not a code issue.  Check your path syntax, it's probably wrong.  The best way I think is to add a simple "Hello World" JSP page to the app and make sure you can load it.  Then you know the path is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I use this class in my main method, what HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse objects do I put in? Where do I get those?

You don't. You shouldn't create a main method! You need to deploy your servlet in a servlet runner, such as Tomcat.